# React Native ScrollView is cut off from the bottom on iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've just encountered a weird issue that I didn't know why it was happening. For some reason, I can't scroll to the bottom of my `<ScrollView>`.

Here's my code: https://repl.it/Iqcx/0

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Problem**: Your nav bar is pushing your `ScrollView` down.

**Solution**: Make the wrapper around your `ScrollView` fill the entire screen. This change in line 8 does the magic: `<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>`

I also changed your code minimally to make it useful for people who don't have your image and to better see what's happening I named the values differently. Here's the working version: https://repl.it/Iqcx/2

Simplified code:

```
import { View, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
  <ScrollView />
</View>
```

Comment: Repl apparently no longer supports react native, the code can no longer be viewed

Answer (score 41):

In my case the issue wasn't `flex: 1` or `flexGrow: 1`, but using **`padding`** on `ScrollView` styles.

So instead of doing this:

```
<ScrollView style={{padding: 40}}>
  {/* MY CONTENT HERE */}
</ScrollView>
```

I did this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <View style={{padding: 40}}>
    {/* MY CONTENT HERE */}
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

And the problem was fixed.

**So if you want to add padding to your `ScrollView`, create a `View` inside it and apply padding to it instead.**

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

> `flex:1` to the outer parent

```
<View> //Parent
 <Header/>
 <ScrollView/>
</View>
```

if `ScrollView` is cutting off, assign parent `<View>` `flex:1`

```
<View style={{flex:1}}> //Parent
 <Header/>
 <ScrollView/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding `flexGrow:1` to the `<ScrollView>` component `contentContainerStyle` prop worked for me (adding `flex:1` to the outside `<View>` or to the `<ScrollView>` was NOT working for me).

```
<View>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}>
    (...content here...)
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my `View` of the element that was cut off, I had a value `height = 100%`

Removing this did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that my main content was set to `position: absolute` so the correct height was not calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the items in my `ScrollView` had its `aspectRatio` set to 1. When I removed that, I was able to scroll to the bottom of the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

In my `ScrollView` component I could scroll to the bottom and see all the content, except there was always an overlay at the bottom while I scroll. I solved this by wrapping the `ScrollView` in a `View` component by doing this I did not see the overlay no more. Hope that this helps somebody.